# Java wait code until JFrame keyPressed

Tags: java, jframe

I'm using a JFrame and I wanted to display an image and pause the code until the user presses ANY key. After that key being pressed the image would close and the code would continue running.

What I did:

- Created a flag

  `final boolean[] flag = {true};`
- Added a addKeyListener to the JFrame object that would change the flag

  ```
  frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      frame.setVisible(false);
      frame.dispose();
      flag[0] = false;
  }
  });
  ```
- Wait loop until flagged

  ```
  while (flag[0]){
      try {
          Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

This is working, but I understand that it is a bit resourceful.

Is there any other way of making the wait loop? Is there any listener of the listener?

2nd try, using **CountDownLatch**:

- Set the latch

  ```
      final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  ```
- CountDown
      for (JFrame frame : framesList) {

  ```
      frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

          @Override
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
          }

          @Override
          public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
          }

          @Override
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                  frame.setVisible(false);
                  frame.dispose();
                  latch.countDown();
          }
      });
  ```
- Wait

  ```
      latch.await();
  ```

Comment: I don't understand this part from your question: `only then I would like to continue the code.`. Could you please explain what you mean by this? Is your application terminating because the JFrame is gone?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I added an example

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get it... can you post the code where you show /change the image? and where exactly is your while loop placed now?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha The full [code is here](https://github.com/Cartucho/OpencvPRs/blob/master/HighGui%20Java/HighGui.java). And I'm calling it from another function with  `Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread( args[0], Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR );
        HighGui.imshow("Colour", img);
        HighGui.waitKey(0);`

        // Show image in GrayScale
        `img = Imgcodecs.imread( args[0], Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
        HighGui.imshow("Gray", img);
        HighGui.waitKey(0);`

Comment: No, that's not how that works, GUIs are event driven. I would consider [the key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` - less focus related issues and a modal dialog (see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)) which will achieve your second requirement

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer I will give it a try!

Comment: @MadProgrammer the thing is that I wanted it to close the JFrame when ANY key is pressed. I added a 2nd try code to the post question.

Comment: @JoãoCartucho Latch approach looks fine to me, but indeed simple modal dialog would do the same thing as eg `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` blocks untill dialog is disposed. If you display the image in dialog, you will achieve both of your goals. Invoking code will continue execution after dialog with image will close.

Comment: @JoãoCartucho Stop trying to "pause" the code execution, you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread which will make your program hang, use a `JDialog`, that's what it's designed to do. *"he thing is that I wanted it to close the JFrame when ANY key is pressed" - You will have no end of issues with `KeyListener`, a better solution would be to set up a default `JButton` on the frame and bind the [Escape] key to close the window - IMHO - as they generally seem to be the most common, user expected, results - which won't require to generate a few dozen lines of code to accomplish

Comment: @JoãoCartucho Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for why things like `Thread.sleep`, `wait`/`notify` or any other blocking approach won't work

Comment: @Antoniossss *"Latch approach looks fine to me"* - Except it's probably blocking the Event Dispatching Thread causing the program to hang

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats jus an assumption... considering given (lack of) context.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yeah it is, but given the "problem description" it's probably not wrong

Comment: @MadProgrammer So lets assume you are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to display an image and have the execution stop until the window is closed.  This just screams modal dialog to me.  A modal dialog will stop the code execution from where it is made visible, it will do it in such away so as not to block the Event Dispatching Thread and make your entire problem come to a screaming halt and hang the program. See [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
                    ImageShower.show(null, img);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ImageShower extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel();

        public ImageShower() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(label);

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "close");
            am.put("close", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(ImageShower.this);
                    if (window != null) {
                        window.dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void setImage(Image img) {
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        }

        public static void show(Component owner, Image img) {
            Window parent = null;
            if (owner != null) {
                parent = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(owner);
            }

            JButton close = new JButton("Close");
            close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(btn);
                    if (window != null) {
                        window.dispose();
                    }
                }
            });

            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            ImageShower shower = new ImageShower();
            shower.setImage(img);
            dialog.add(shower);
            dialog.add(close, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            dialog.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(close);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

}
```

*"But wait, may images are large and take time to load and I don't want to freeze the UI while the load"*...

Okay, for that, I'd look towards using a `SwingWorker`, which can load the image in the background but which provides simple methods for ensuring the the image is displayed within the context of the EDT properly...

```
public class ImageLoadAndShow extends SwingWorker<Void, Image> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
        publish(img);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Image> chunks) {
        Image img = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        ImageShower.show(null, img);
    }

}
```

Not, if the image fails to load, you won't know about it, as the `doInBackground` method will pass the `Exception` out of the method.  You'd need to use a combination of a `PropertyChangeListener` and the `SwingWorker`s `get` method to trap it, just remember, `get` is blocking, so calling it inside the context of the EDT will block until the worker completes

*"But I need to carry out other operations when the dialog is closed"*

There are a few ways you might be able to achieve this, depending on what it is you want to do, for this example, I've stuck with the `SwingWorker`, because it was easy to copy and paste the basic structure, but you could use a `Runnable` wrapped in a `Thread`

```
public class ImageLoadShowAndWait extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImageShower.show(null, img);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, if none of that does what you want...then I'd like to know what it is you're actually doing :P, have a look at [Foxtrot](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/docs/introduction.php) which provides an API which allows you to execute code asynchronisly within the EDT without blocking it (entirly), but which will stop the code execution at the point it's called until it completes

> The thing is that I wanted it to close the JFrame when ANY key is pressed

`KeyListener` is going to give you issues, maybe not today, maybe not tomorrow, but it will blow up in your face eventually.  The example I've provide binds the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key to dispose of the window.  It also makes the "Close" button the default button, which provides <kbd>Space</kbd> and/or <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys as well and a nice visual queue to the user.

If you want to use `KeyListener`, that's up to you, but your core problem doesn't seem to revolve around it, but the ability to display a window and pause the code execution till it's closed

Comment: It worked great! The reason why I'm doing this is that I'm trying to do the OpenCV HighGui module for the Java API, and if I'm able to do it this will help lots of people.

Comment: [Code Here](https://github.com/Cartucho/OpencvPRs/blob/master/HighGui%20Java/HighGui2.java), is it ok if I call the Class from a specific method instead of the main? I wanted people just to do `HighGui2.imshow("title", imgMat);`

Comment: Yep, call it from wherever you need it, just make sure you call from within the context of the EDT

Comment: So can I erase the main method? If I wanted to show more than one image/dialog at a time would you recommend joining them all together in the same JPanel or keeping separate windows?

Comment: @JoãoCartucho Well, you don't need my `main` method, but you're going t need one eventually. If you wanted to show more then one image at a time, I'd be tempted to use a single window